# reading the line after re.match

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to read xyz coordinates from a long file using python.
within the file there is a block which indicates that the xyz coordinates are within the next lines.

```
CARTESIAN COORDINATES (ANGSTROEM)
---------------------------------
  C     -0.283576   -0.776740   -0.312605
  H     -0.177080   -0.046256   -1.140653
  Cl    -0.166557    0.025928    1.189976

----------------------------
```

I'm using the following code to find the line which mentions the "CARTESIAN COORDINATES (ANGSTROEM)" and then try to iterate until finding an empty line to read the coordinates. However, f.tell() points that I'm at line 0! Therefore, I can not do either next(f) or f.readline() to go through the next lines (just goes to line 1 from line 0). I don't know how this can be done with python.

```
def read_xyz_out(self,out):
    atoms = []
    x = []
    y = []
    z = []
    f = open(out, "r")
    for line in open(out):
        if re.match(r'{}'.format(r'CARTESIAN COORDINATES \(ANGSTROEM\)'), line):
            print(f.tell())
             #    data = line.split()
             #    atoms.append(data[0])
             #    x.append(float(data[1]))
             #    y.append(float(data[2]))
             #    z.append(float(data[3]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you read your file into this string:

```
My dog has fleas.
CARTESIAN COORDINATES (ANGSTROEM)
---------------------------------
  C     -0.283576   -0.776740   -0.312605
  H     -0.177080   -0.046256   -1.140653
  Cl    -0.166557    0.025928    1.189976

----------------------------

My cat too.
```

You can then extract lines 4, 5 and 6 with the regular expression

```
/CARTESIAN COORDINATES \(ANGSTROEM\)\r?\n---------------------------------\r?\n(.+?)(?=\r?\n\r?\n)/s
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/gOwkCf/3/)

This expression reads, "match the string 'CARTENSION...---\r?\n' followed by matching 1+ chars, greedily, in capture group 1, followed by an empty line, with the flag '/s' to enable '.' to match the ends of lines".

The desired information can then be extracted with the regular expression

```
/ *([A-Z][a-z]*) +(-?\d+.\d{6}) +(-?\d+.\d{6}) +(-?\d+.\d{6})\r?\n/
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/AU4WTR/3/)

The first step can be skipped if it is sufficient to look for a line that look like this:

```
C     -0.283576   -0.776740   -0.312605
```

without having to confirm it is preceded by "CARTESIAN...---".

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/AU4WTR/5/)

Answer (score 1):

You've opened `out` twice: once for the `f` variable and a second time for the `for line in open(out):` loop. Each `file` object has its own position, and you've only been reading from the second one (which hasn't been assigned to a variable so you can't get the position). The position of `f` is still at the beginning, since you never read from it.

You should use

```
for line in f:
```

and not call `open(out)` a second time. You can then call `f.readline()` inside the loop to read more lines of the file.

Answer (score 1):

How about this (note: untested so there's bound to be bugs - think of this as a sketch of a solution):

```
def read_xyz_out(self,out):
    atoms = []
    x = []
    y = []
    z = []
    f = open(out, "r")

    # Read until you get to the data
    for line in f:
        if re.match(r'{}'.format(r'CARTESIAN COORDINATES \(ANGSTROEM\)'), line):
            # skip the next line too
            f.readline()
            break

     # Now you're into the data - the loop here picks up where the previous
     # one left off
     for line in f:
             data = line.split()
             atoms.append(data[0])
             x.append(float(data[1]))
             y.append(float(data[2]))
             z.append(float(data[3]))
    f.close()
```